# Filter datagrid by datepicker

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a data grid which contains all the records from a database, I have managed to filter the results by first and last name, but when I try to filter the records by a datepicker it doesn't return any results.

```
private void DbSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string connectionString = @"Data Source = (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB; AttachDbFilename = C:\Users\Scott\Desktop\DatabaseV4\Apptest\Apptest\Records.mdf; Integrated Security = True";

        using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            sqlCon.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter SqlDA = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Records WHERE FirstName like '" + DatabaseFName.Text + "%' AND LastName like '" + DatabaseLName.Text + "%' AND DOB like '" + dateTimePicker2.Value.Date + "%' ", sqlCon);
            DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();
            SqlDA.Fill(dtbl);

            dataGridView2.DataSource = dtbl;

        }
```

Comment: You have an extraneous wild card character (use = not like with dates). But please do not build queries like this. Read up on SQL injection. Use parameters instead. If you use parameters, then you will not need to worry about the formatting of the date, instead it is passed as a date type. There are plenty of examples here and elsewhere to show you how to do this, which you can find with very little effort.

Comment: Thanks that worked